# Abstract Algebra groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $(G, *, e)$ be a finite group, and let $p$ be an odd prime number. Consider the equation
$x^p = e$ for an element $x$ of $G$. Show that the number of solutions $x \in G$ is odd.

Comment: Hint: what's the relation between the order of $<x>$ and $G$?

Answer (score 0):

Each solution of $x^p=e$ gives rise to a subgroup of order $p$, though different solutions may define the same subgroup. Each such subgroup contains $p-1$ non-trivial solutions. If there are $k$ such subgroups, then we have $k(p-1)+1$ solutions. Since $p$ is odd, this number is also odd.